# Weird result to a differential equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)\cdot \:f\left(x\right)-\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\cdot \left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)=0$$

I tried to solve a differential equation and after doing some math I came up to this.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4):

After cleaning up the notation a bit, this is:

$$(f' - f)'\cdot f - (f' - f)\cdot f'$$

We recognize this as the numerator in the quotient rule for the derivative of $\frac{f' - f}{f}$:

$$\left(\frac{f' - f}{f}\right)' = \frac{(f' - f)'\cdot f - (f' - f)\cdot f'}{f^2}$$

So the differential equation becomes:

$$f^2\left(\frac{f' - f}{f}\right)' = (f' - f)'\cdot f - (f' - f)\cdot f' = 0$$

Assumming $f(x) \neq 0$ over a connected open interval $I$, then for $x \in I$ we have:
$$\left(\frac{f' - f}{f}\right)' = 0$$

Which means that $\frac{f' - f}{f} = \lambda - 1$ for some constant $\lambda$.

Finally we obtain the first-order ODE $f' = \lambda f$ with solutions $$f(x) = Ce^{\lambda x}$$ where $C$ is any constant, and the solution is valid for $x \in I$.

However since $f$ must be continuous, it can't ever equal zero unless $C = 0$, so the solution is valid for all $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $g = f'-f$, where I use the notation $f'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(f(x))$, your equation can be written
$$ g' f - f' g = 0$$

Remark first that $f=0$ is obviously solution. Assume now that $f$ is not the function $0$ and is a continuous solution of your equation, then there is an interval such that $|f|$ is strictly positive and on this interval
$$(g/f)' = \frac{g' f - f' g}{f^2} = 0$$
from which we deduce that $g=Cf$ for some constant $C$, so that $f'-f = Cf$, from which we get $f' = (C+1) f$ and $f(x) = f(0)\,e^{(C+1)x}$. Conversely every fonction of the form
$$f(x) = C_0 e^{C_1 x}$$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\md{\mathrm{d}}$
The other two answers discuss how to solve the differential equation once we notice that the quotient rule was applied.

We can also solve it using the substitution $u = \dfrac{\md f}{\md x}$.

---

We can express the given differential equation as
$$\big(f''(x)- f'(x)\big)f(x) - \big(f'(x)\big)^2 + f(x)f'(x)=0.$$

For brevity, we will denote $f''(x)$ by $f''$ and $f'(x)$ by $f'$.

Then, the given differential equation simplifies to $f''f = \big(f'\big)^2$.

If we let $u = \dfrac{\md f}{\md x}$, then, applying the Chain Rule, we get
$$\dfrac{\md u}{\md x} = \dfrac{\md u}{\md f}\dfrac{\md f}{\md x} = u\dfrac{\md u}{\md f}.$$

Therefore, the original differential equation becomes
$$\begin{align*}
&\phantom{{}\implies{}}\Big(u\dfrac{\md u}{\md f}\Big)f = u^2 \\
&\implies \dfrac{\md u}{u} = \dfrac{\md f}{f}
\end{align*}$$

This implies that $\ln u = \ln f + \ln c_1$, which is equivalent to $u = c_1f$.

But since $u = \dfrac{\md f}{\md x}$, we get yet another first order separable differential equation:
$$\dfrac{\md f}{\md x} = c_1 f$$

Solving this one gives us $\ln f = c_1x + \ln c_2$, which means that
$$f(x) = c_2 e^{c_1 x}$$
where $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. If $c_2 = 0$, then we get the trivial solution, namely $f(x) = 0$.